# How to convert ModelAndView Spring MVC to spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How do I convert the following Spring MVC code to spring webflux?

```
@GetMapping(path = "/connect")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
public ModelAndView connect() {
  
    String oauthUrl = "https://google.com";
    RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView(oauthUrl);
    redirect.setExpandUriTemplateVariables(false);
    return new ModelAndView(redirect);
  }
```

Comment: Webflux is not applicable for MVC which returns model and view. It is applicable only to return model data alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RestController

public class TestController {


        @GetMapping(path = "/redirect")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> redirect() {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)
                .header("Location", "https://google.com?param=ABCD")
                .build());
    }
}
```

or the `.header(...)` can be replaced by `.location(new URI(...))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rendering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.14/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/Rendering.html) for that.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/redirect")
public class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<Rendering> redirect() {
        return Mono.just(Rendering.redirectTo("https://www.google.com").build());
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work, I get response body `{}` and header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Are you using the `@Controller` annotation on your controller class? See my updated sample code, this works just finde on my local demo.

Comment: Still does not work, same rspons, I can debug and see the stop at the break point.
I'm using `@RestController`

Comment: You should use `@Controller` when you need rendering. As the name implies `@RestController` is used for REST endpoints and therefore expects `application/json` content type.